# Extending dimensions of netCDF file using NCO

Tags: python, netcdf, nco

Is there a NCO or netCDF4 command that can be used to extend the lat-lon dimensions of netCDF file.

E.g. I have a netCDF file with foll. dimensons:

dimensions(sizes): time(10), var(1), latitude(1674), longitude(4320)

I want to extend the latitude dimension to cover the entire globe i.e. instead of 1674 it should be 2160. Is there a way to do that? The new cells should be assigned a user-specified value say 0.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could generate a new grid of the size you want and then remap your original data to that grid with [ncremap](http://nco.sf.net/nco.html#ncremap). It's a fairly sophisticated feature but then so is what you want to do :). Or you could open your file in [ncap2](http://nco.sf.net/nco.html#ncap2), define new dimensions of the sizes above, and then use hyperslab subscripting to copy your original data into a corner of your new array, then use ncks to extract only the new fields/dimensions from that file.